# Make custom Wordpress comments list

Tags: loop, comments

i'm making a custom Wordpress template and I've made this HTML code for single comment template:

```
            <div class="comment" id="1">
          <div class="useravatar" style="background-image: url('[LINK]')"></div>
          <div class="textbox">
              <div class="dateauthor">[AUTHOR NAME] <span class="date">[DATE]</span></div>
              <div class="text">
                [COMMENT TEXT]
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

But i'm getting only headache to find out how to make a loop o something else where I can use this.

Is there any good example for this cases?

Answer (score 0):

You have just created the template. You still need to create the entire function of the form. It would be easier to just copy a comment.php and then edit it out with some CSS to get it to look like what you want it to. The link below is for a default comment.php that should work for you. https://gist.github.com/mpsparrow/51965f9eedba5d5e7492